# How to store some browser data in PC storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest

I am developing a chrome extension for web automation that can record and automate the browser. For this, I have to type text in input fields or text areas. Setting the value attribute doesn't work on all websites. Also dispatchevent method doesn't work because of that isTrusted set to false. I don't know if it's possible to use node js libraries like puppeteer or Cypress in manifest!!

I am not sure how to approach this. If anybody can pls help...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.